# How to confirm the $k$-th power of this matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

For any $k \in \mathbb N$,

$$\begin{bmatrix}2&-2\\0.5&0\end{bmatrix}^k = \begin{bmatrix}k+1&-2k\\k/2&-(k-1)\end{bmatrix}$$

I found this empirically using numerical computation, but I cannot prove it. I have tried computing the eigendecomposition, but this matrix is not diagonalizable.

Comment: Try bi-directional induction on $k\in \Bbb Z$ beginning with $k=0$. That is, if it's true for $k\in \Bbb Z$ then it's true for $k\pm 1.$

Comment: You get better responses if you compose your title better. E.g. "How to confirm the $k$th power of this matrix?"

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Following Surb's hint, I have proved it. Your suggestion is exactly what I did. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet  Thanks again. I have edited the title accordingly.

Comment: Valid for all integers, not just natural numbers.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo  You are right. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**

Induction should work better.

Comment: Thanks! I did not think about that. Now I have the proof.

Comment: you are welcome :-) @user5228

Answer (score 6):

Using the Cayley-Hamilton Theorem, the characteristic polynomial is:
$$p(\lambda)=\det(\lambda I_2-A)=\begin{vmatrix}\lambda-2&2\\ -0.5&\lambda\end{vmatrix}=\lambda^2-2\lambda+1=0.$$
Hence:
$$p(A)=A^2-2A+I=0 \Rightarrow A^2=2A-I.$$
Thus:
$$\begin{align}A^2&=2A-I;\\
A^3&=A^2A=(2A-I)A=2A^2-A=2(2A-I)-A=3A-2I;\\
A^4&=A^3A=(3A-2I)A=3A^2-2A=3(2A-I)-2A=4A-3I;\\
\vdots \\
A^k&=kA-(k-1)I=k\begin{pmatrix}2&-2\\0.5&0\end{pmatrix}-(k-1)\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}k+1&-2k\\0.5k&-(k-1)\end{pmatrix}.\\
\end{align}$$

Comment: The Cayley-Hamilton Theorem is new to me. Now I have learned a new approach. Thanks!

Comment: you are welcome. good luck.

Answer (score 5):

The matrix (call it $A$) may not be diagonalizable, but it does split into the sum of the identity matrix and a nilpotent matrix: $$N = A-I = \begin{bmatrix}1&-2\\\frac12&-1\end{bmatrix}.$$ Since $N$ and $I$ commute you can expand $A^k$ using the binomial theorem: $$A^k = I + kN + \binom k2N^2 + \dots,$$ but since $N^2=0$, all of the terms that involve that and higher powers of $N$ vanish and you have $A^k=I+kN=kA+(1-k)I$.

This method works for any $2\times2$ matrix with a repeated eigenvalue $\lambda$: it will split into $A=\lambda I+N$ with $N^2=0$, and by the binomial formula $$A^k = \lambda^k I+k\lambda^{k-1}N = k\lambda^{k-1}A + (1 - k)\lambda^k I.$$

Comment: very nice approach! I guess that for $n\geq 2$, $A$ splits into $I+\lambda N$ if all eigenvalues are equal.

Comment: @Surb It’s $\lambda I+N$, but yes. Similar decompositions are possible for any non-diagonalizable matrix with all real eigenvalues, but they become cumbersome even for $3\times3$ matrices. However, you can always use the underlying idea, which is that the Cayley-Hamilton theorem ensures that any analytic function of an $n\times n$ matrix can be expressed as an $(n-1)$th degree polynomial. Finding the coefficients of that polynomial involves solving a linear system of $n$ equations in $n$ unknowns.

Comment: @amd I can now understand why $a=\pm 2$ are the special cases (see my comments to Rodrigo de Azevedo's answer). If we want the $2\times2$ matrix to have repeated eigenvalues, $a$ must be 2 or -2. Then we have $N^2=0$, which makes the $k$th power a clean and short form.

Answer (score 3):

Using [SymPy](http://www.sympy.org):

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> A = Matrix([[            2,  -2],
                [Rational(1,2),   0]])
```

Computing the Jordan normal form,

```
>>> P, J = A.jordan_form()
>>> P
Matrix([[-5/2, -1/2],
        [-5/4,    1]])
>>> J
Matrix([[1, 1],
        [0, 1]])
```

Using the binomial theorem, we conclude that the $k$-th power of Jordan matrix $\rm J$ is $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & k\\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$. Thus,

```
>>> k = Symbol('k', integer=True)
>>> P * Matrix([[1, k],[0, 1]]) * P**-1
Matrix([[k + 1,   -2*k],
        [  k/2, -k + 1]])
```

However, [SymPy](http://www.sympy.org) is "smart" enough to compute the $k$-th power of $\rm A$:

```
>>> A**k
Matrix([[k + 1,   -2*k],
        [  k/2, -k + 1]])
```

Comment: Is this really easier than [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B2,-2%7D,%7B1%2F2,0%7D%7D%5Ek)?

Comment: @Surb WA requires an Internet connection.

Comment: true :), but I guess OP has an internet connection otherwise it might difficult to post here. Anyway, the approach you suggest has also value in that it describes the mechanism behind computing matrix powers.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo  Trying to see if this result can be generalized, so I tried $\left[\begin{array}{cc}a&-a\\1/a&0\end{array}\right]^k$ at WA, the result was interesting. It seems that a=2 is a special case. Thank you for your answer--I was going to ask a more general question of how to compute algebraically the k-th power of a matrix that is not diagonalizable, but your answer gave me at least one approach to follow. Also thanks for editing the question--it is now formal, and in proper mathematical terms.

Comment: @user5228 The case $a = -2$ is also special. Note that the discriminant of the characteristic polynomial is $a^2 - 4$, which vanishes at $a = \pm 2$.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo  Right. I have been dealing with positive numbers for too long. :)